# How to add button to the last section of the UItableviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i would like to add last section of UiTableviewcontroller with image button.

In my app i have taken TableViewController.

In that i set table view style as grouped data. I have created section in table view.

Now i want to put Custom button in the last section of table view which scroll with the table 
view . 
How to set last section with custom button image?

Comment: create a uibutton with cgrectmake and place the image of the button you like http://developer.casgrain.com/?p=100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a button on the bottom of a table view by several ways. You can add the button as the footer view of the table (or as the footer view of the last section of the table view).

```
tableView.tableFooterView = theImageButton;
```

If you really want to have it in a section, you can add the last section with just 1 row and add the button as the subview of the cell's contentView.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:theImageButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the button to **tableview.tablefooterView**.

I use that way in the case you described.

Answer (score 1):

Adding into footer is really easy to implement. You can add anything as a view there button/image
[cell.contentView addSubview:view];